# how to send array of object in ajax post request asp.net core mvc razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to send array of object to web Api post ActionResult method

**my array of objects looks like this**

```
model:[{"Status":"HOLD","MessageId":1},{"Status":"HOLD","MessageId":2}]
```

**post request from front-end in .cshtml file**

```
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: "Home/postMessage",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
           console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

**web api code looks like this**

**PostStatus model**

```
public class PostStatus
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public int MessageId { get; set; }
    }
```

**post Request code in controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult postMessage(PostStatus model)
{
    return  Json(new { data = model });
}
```

debugging snip of above web api post request code

[image]

I WAS UNABLE FIND THE ISSUE WHERE IT WAS CAUSING THE PROBLEM.

Comment: You are sending an array. But your action method parameter is a single object. Either change it to an collection of PostStatus or send a single object from client side

Comment: @Shyju I have tried that but data is null in web api endpoint I will attach a snip in a short while.

Comment: See the answer I posted below which should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your client side code, you are sending an array of items, but in your server side action method, your action method parameter is a single object of `PostStatus` class. When the form is submitted, the default model binder will read and parse the submitted form data and try to map it to your parameter object property values. Since your parameter type and the posted data are different types, model binder cannot properly map the values.

You should use a collection type as the parameter and model binder will be able to bind the posted form data to that. Also decorate your action method parameter with `FromBody` attribute, which tells the model binder to read the data from the request body.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult postMessage([FromBody] IEnumerable<PostStatus> model)
{
    return Json(new { data = model });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Shyju
I have added collection in my action method parameter the mistake I have done is not adding [FromBody] 
I have added that and it is working.

Comment: @stom sure, Thanks for suggestion.